# How can I reverse order the toctree provided by the "glob" flag option?

Tags: sorting, python-sphinx, glob, toctree

Does anyone know any option to order toctree in descending order of the filenames?
In case of ascending order, we can use `:glob:` option like this:

```
.. toctree:
   :glob:

   2011*
```

This would be handy for daily notes written in restructured text that should be reported within a Sphinx document.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There is no simple option to reverse-sort the toctree. But you can do it by modifying the document structure before it is written to file. Here is a suggestion. Add the following code to **conf.py**:

```py
def reverse_toctree(app, doctree, docname):
    """Reverse the order of entries in the root toctree if 'glob' is used."""
    if docname == "index":
        for node in doctree.traverse():
            if node.tagname == "toctree" and node.get("glob"):
                node["entries"].reverse()
                break

def setup(app):
    app.connect("doctree-resolved", reverse_toctree)
```

The `reverse_toctree()` callback function is called when the `doctree-resolved` event is fired. The function locates the `toctree` node in the document tree and changes it in-place.

More details about Sphinx and Docutils APIs:

- https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/extdev/appapi.html
- http://docutils.sourceforge.net/docs/ref/doctree.html

Comment: Nice.  Wouldn't this reverse every toctree though?  You can probably add a check for a `:reversed: parameter to the toctree node to control this behavior, no?

Comment: @Kevin Horn: The code reverses the toctree in the "index" (root) document if the :glob: option is used. The OP has not specified any detailed requirements, and I did not intend this answer to be more than a humble suggestion. I am sure that there are many ways to tweak it. Thanks for the comment and the upvote!

Comment: But this doesn't reverse the ToC in the sidebar.

Answer (score 12):

This adds a reversed option to toctree.

```py
from sphinx.directives import TocTree
from docutils.parsers.rst import directives

class NewTocTree(TocTree):
    option_spec = dict(TocTree.option_spec,
                       reversed=directives.flag)

    def run(self):
        rst = super(NewTocTree, self).run()
        if 'reversed' in self.options:
            rst[0][0]['entries'].reverse()
        return rst

def setup(app):
    app.add_directive('toctree', NewTocTree)
```

Which lets you do:

```
Contents:

.. toctree::
   :maxdepth: 2
   :reversed:
   :glob:

   20*
```

Comment: This also reverses the toctree in the sidebar.

Answer (score 5):

As of Sphinx 1.5+ there is a built-in `:reversed:` flag you can add to a toctree:

```
.. toctree::
   :glob:
   :reversed:

   2011*
```

For more information, see [the Sphinx documentation](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/stable/markup/toctree.html).

Comment: The feature was added in Sphinx 1.5 (1.5a2): http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/stable/changes.html#id30.